# Highcharts Setup Export Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have setup the server for export of highcharts . Followed all the steps mentioned at http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server.

The export server URL is

```
http://myhostname:8080/highcharts-export-web
```

Now as per highchart documentation I have changed the highchart option export 'url' to

```
http://myhostname:8080/highcharts-export-web.
```

Below is the snippet of the code.

```
exporting: {
                          sourceWidth: 3000,
                          sourceHeight: 1000,
                          scale: 5,
                          url : "http://myhostname:8080/highcharts-export-web"
                }
```

But when highchart export button is clicked , my page is redirected to `"http://myhostname:8080/highcharts-export-web"`. So, chart is not exported at all as my chart page is being redirected to the export server page.

Am I missing anything in the configuration due to which whole page is redirected instead of doing simple ajax post.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Any errors in js console or on the server? Try to use `"http://myhostname:8080/highcharts-export-web/"` also.

Comment: The ending `/` is required.

Comment: The redirect issue is solved by adding / at the end. But now the time out error is reported 'Oops..,Sorry, the server is handling too many requests at the moment. Please try again'. - Rahul

Comment: Hard to say what's the reason. Check [this topic](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/java-export-server-t28759).

Comment: This might be an issue regarding phantom.js. It is possible that it is not able to find path for phantom.js